# Getting endless "This webpage was reloaded because a problem occurred" errors

Tags: safari, high-sierra

After some indeterminate amount of time (or some unknown event?), I can't open a new Safari window or tab, without getting the message "This webpage was reloaded because a problem occurred" animating down onto the window in an endless loop.

[image: This webpage was reloaded because a problem occurred]

I can reload pages that were already open, and I can browse within a window/tab that was already open, but can't open a new window or tab. Even command-clicking a link from an already-open tab to open that link in a new window results in an empty window, as if I had just opened it (no URL it's trying to load).

I've tried disabling all extensions, but that doesn't help. Ultimately, quitting and relaunching Safari solves it, but then I need to move a bunch of windows across different spaces back where they belong. That's a pain, and I'd rather not have to do that. Any ideas?

I'm on an up-to-date High Sierra (10.13.6), with the stock version of Safari (12.0).

Comment: Can you please re-check the version of Safari. The current public version as of macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 is Version 11.1.2 (13605.3.8).

Comment: If you're using v12 that's a beta version.  I've not found any solution to the closing/reopening routine that you've already discovered.  You would need to opt-out of the beta testing to eliminate this.  You should also use the Apple Bug Reporter to report this.

Comment: I've only ever seen that error when I did actually have a connectivity issue [my ISP was messing with the line for an hour]. I'm also on Safari 12.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Thanks, I think I must have gotten on the beta without realizing (I used that machine to download the installer)

Comment: @Dov Are you able to verify the error is no longer appearing after reverting to the stable release? On another note, Safari 12.0 for macOS High Sierra is released publicly and can be installed via Update in Mac App Store.

Comment: Im on Safari 11.1.2 and get the reloads all the time. Basic ajax seems to cause reloads. Safari is trash.

Comment: My work Mac was recently updated and I now have 13.0.2. I've had this Mac for two years and it's been fine. I've had a hundred+ tabs open in the past for weeks at a time with no problem. After updating, I get the looping "This webpage was reloaded..." animation every couple days, with only a dozen windows open. The only cure is quitting and relaunching.

Comment: I followed the steps in this website https://appletoolbox.com/a-problem-occurred-with-this-webpage-so-it-was-reloaded-fix/ and fixed the issue :  Happening on Your Mac?
Go to the Safari > Preferences > Privacy > Remove All Website Data
Remove Safari’s Cache
Close Safari
On the Finder Top Menu, navigate to Go > Go to Folder
Type: ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db and press return
Move that file to your Mac’s trash or to your desktop
Launch Safari